# data.table v.1.11.0+ no longer freads data file that was fread by v.1.10.4-3

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I've encountered a possible bug in the new version of `data.table`. I have a 2GB .csv file with c. 3 million rows and 67 columns. I can use `fread()` to read it all fine from data.table v.1.10.4-3, but v.1.11.0+ terminates at a row somewhere down the middle. The base `read.csv()` also hits the same problem. I really like `data.table` and want to create a bug report on Github, but obviously I can't upload the 2GB data file anywhere.

I need a way of splicing maybe ~10 rows around the problematic point (the row number is known) in order to create a portable reproducible example. Any ideas how I can do that without reading in the .csv file?

Also, is there a program I can use to open the raw file to look at the problematic point and see what causes the issue? Notepad/Excel won't open a file this big.

EDIT: [the verbose output](https://pastebin.com/SUx6wSQF).

EDIT2: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIcrf.png) is the problematic line. It shows that what is supposed to be one line is somehow split into 3 lines. I can only assume it is due to an export bug in an ancient software (SAP Business Objects) that was used to create the CSV. It is unsurprising that it causes an issue. However, it surprising that `data.table` v.1.10.4-3 was able to handle it in a smart way and read it correctly, whereas v.1.11.0+ could not. Could it do something with encoding or technical hidden characters?

EDIT3: [proof](https://streamable.com/qxxjk) that this is what really happens.

Comment: Try specifying `verbose = TRUE` in `fread` and see what it tells you.

Comment: 2GB is not that big. You could upload it to a dropbox of whatever. You should really report this issue to the data.table GitHub repo.

Comment: What is the operating system of the computer you're using?

Comment: Using Windows 7 64-bit (work laptop). [This](https://pastebin.com/SUx6wSQF) is the verbose output.

Comment: Can't upload 2GB anyway, as it is private. Uploading no more than a few rows should be OK though.

Comment: So it tells you what's the issue is and in what row. Try specifying `fill=TRUE` or skip that line

Comment: @Mihael: You need Notepad++ 64bit to open big files https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.5.6.html

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for including the output. It shows that `fread` is issuing a warning. Did you miss this warning before?

`Warning message:
In fread("Data/FP17s with TCD in March 2018.csv", na.strings = c("#EMPTY",  :
  Stopped early on line 138986. Expected 67 fields but found 22. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<916439/0001,Q69,GDS Contract,MR A SYED,916439,Mr,SYED A Mr,A,SYED,58955,3718.00,Nine Mile Ride Dental Practice,Dental Surgery,193 Nine Mile Ride,Finchampstead,WOKINGHAM,RG40 4JD,2181233168.00,TORIN,FASTNEDGE,1 ANCHORITE CLOSE,>>`

This is very helpful, surely. It tells you the line number: 138986. It says that this line is 22 fields but it expects 67. Could the warning be better by stating why it is expecting 67 fields at that point (e.g. by saying there are 67 column names and it has seen 67 columns up to that point?)  It gives you a hint of what to try (`fill=TRUE`) which would fill that too-short line with NA in columns 23:67. Then it includes the data from the line, too.

Does it work with `fill=TRUE`, as the warning message suggests?

You say it worked in 1.10.4-3 but I suspect it's more likely it stopped early there too, but without warning. If so, that was a bug not to warn, now fixed.

Comment: It doesn't work with `fill=TRUE` as all lines after that problematic row are shifted to the wrong columns. I had some help here and on Github where I created the [ticket](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2857), and will work to create a reproducible example.

Comment: It definitely works 1.10.4-3 and not in 1.11.0+. In the latter case, the size of the DT read is 138985 rows, in the former it is 3+ million rows with all columns in the right places.

Comment: Please see my EDIT2 in the post, showing the issue in Notepad++.

Comment: Also see [this](https://streamable.com/qxxjk) as proof that this is what really happens.

Comment: Sorry for too many comments, I've created an [issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2857) on Github if you want to follow that.

Answer (score 1):

Using Powershell on Windows:

```
Get-Content YourFile.csv | Select -Index (0,19,20,21,22) > OutputFileName.csv
```

would dump the header and lines 20-23 into a new file.

Comment: excuse me, but If I would delete some rows, what is the correct code?

Answer (score 1):

**Use a combination of `skip` and `nrow`:**

You mentioned that you have no problem reading the file with v.1.10.4-3, right?. So use that to `skip` most of the `.csv` and set `nrow` to the number of rows you want. Once you have that data.table, you can write that portion of the file and you have a portable reproducible example.

**For example:**

`DT <- fread(my_file.csv, skip=138981, nrow=10)`